# Android GCM- GCMRegistrar checkManifest(this) - Manifest File Error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I try to implement GCM, but i get an error, i try to find logs internet but i can't.
When code comes these lines, i get error at logcat

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
```

What means this logcat output?

```
09-11 11:14:25.132: W/dalvikvm(11946): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0x40aac210)
09-11 11:14:25.142: E/AndroidRuntime(11946): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[ManagePushCommunicationService]
09-11 11:14:25.142: E/AndroidRuntime(11946): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.example.push.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
09-11 11:14:25.142: E/AndroidRuntime(11946):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(GCMRegistrar.java:135)
09-11 11:14:25.142: E/AndroidRuntime(11946):    at com.example.push.services.ManagePushCommunicationService.startJob(ManagePushCommunicationService.java:156)
09-11 11:14:25.142: E/AndroidRuntime(11946):    at com.example.push.services.ManagePushCommunicationService.onHandleIntent(ManagePushCommunicationService.java:85)
09-11 11:14:25.142: E/AndroidRuntime(11946):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
09-11 11:14:25.142: E/AndroidRuntime(11946):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 11:14:25.142: E/AndroidRuntime(11946):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 11:14:25.142: E/AndroidRuntime(11946):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-11 11:19:25.162: I/Process(11946): Sending signal. PID: 11946 SIG: 9
```

Comment: did you managed to get it working because a lot of people are getting this error by following the android developers example code and its very frustrating?

Comment: You must be checking this in emulator.

Answer (score 5):

Put permission in manifest File:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Found that the name declaration must be exactly right to work.
"com.example.gcm" must be replaced with the package name to the activity using C2D.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your manifest

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.push.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.push.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Plz Follow the Following Steps**

**1.** Include "gcm.jar" in libs in your Application

**2.** Android SDK Manager => Extras => Install Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library (Obsolete)

**3.** Android SDK Manager => Android 4.3 (API 18) => Install Google APIs

Answer (score 0):

Give permission as

```
<permission android:name="your package name.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="your package name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```